# MYSQL Order By W/Count

Tags: mysql, count, sql-order-by

My table has usernames and points of user, and I am working on a leader boards list. I would like to get the top ten players based on points. I have formulated this query as:

```
SELECT
    users.username,
    users.points
FROM users
ORDER BY users.points DESC
LIMIT 10
```

However, I would also like to get where the player stands in accordance to the number 1 player, without creating a new column for it. Is there a MYSQL query to get the `ORDER BY DESC` by points as well as `COUNT` from that `ORDER` to find the user in the list? (`WHERE username=`).

Edit for clarification: I would like the count of the users from desc by the above statement. I.E. 1 - user1 - 1000 points, 2 - user2 - 750 points.. etc etc... N - currentPlayer - currentPoints. I don't mind using a `JOIN` statement, but I don't want to have a new column of players sorted by ranking.

Comment: Could you please explain this a little more: "Is there a MYSQL query to get the ORDER BY DESC by points as well as COUNT from that ORDER ". COUNT of what?

Comment: What do you mean you don't want to create a new column?  You don't want a column permanently in your table, or you don't want to even do a `JOIN` in any way?

Comment: Are you looking for a percentile tile rank? So us your table structure and a desired result.

Comment: Edited for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select @rownum:=@rownum+1 `rank`, u.username, u.points 
    from users u, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
    order by points desc) AS X
WHERE username ="Bob";
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  username varchar (30),
  points INT
  );

INSERT INTO users(username,points)
VALUES ('Bob', 1000), ('Jack',750), ('Joe', 500)
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc023/5)

Comment: @brutalhonesty I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: Anyway I could add another delimiter for a column like city or state? So current position based on their city or state? Thanks!

Comment: @brutalhonesty yes you could. Use the same format as above. If the city or state info is inside the user table you can do this without a join. Add to the nested select query the city or state of choice. For example, `(
    select @rownum:=@rownum+1 `rank`, u.username, u.points, u.city 
    from users u, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r WHERE u.city = "New York"
    order by points desc) AS X`

Comment: @brutalhonesty exactly.  Nice trick with the WHERE BINARY that way you get case sensitive results from you query instead of case insensitive ones.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT users.username, users.points FROM users WHERE users.points=MAX(users.points) OR users.username='<comparison username>' ORDER BY users.points DESC;
```

Comment: No luck with this statement, there is no COUNT of the users current position in the leader board.