# Order By Issue with MySQL vs SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have one SQL query in **SQL Server** like this

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY _no ORDER BY _no asc) = 1 THEN 
                        _no ELSE '' END 
    as row_no,
    _no,
    _name,
    r._names
FROM
(
    SELECT '1' as _no, 'vikas' as _name UNION ALL
    SELECT '1', 'kratika' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2', 'vikas' UNION ALL
    SELECT '1', 'kratika kastwar' 
) t
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT '1' as _nos, 'One' as _names UNION ALL
    SELECT '2', 'two' 
) r
ON r._nos = t._no
ORDER BY _no
```

Output:

```
row_no _no  _name           _names
------ ---- --------------- ------
1      1    kratika         One
       1    kratika kastwar One
       1    vikas           One
2      2    vikas           two
```

And the same I am doing in **MySQL** like this

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN _no = @i THEN '' ELSE @i := _no END
    as row_no,
    _no,
    _name,
    r._names
FROM
(
    SELECT '1' as _no, 'vikas' as _name UNION ALL
    SELECT '1', 'kratika' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2', 'vikas' UNION ALL
    SELECT '1', 'kratika kastwar' 
) t
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT '1' as _nos, 'One' as _names UNION ALL
    SELECT '2', 'two' 
) r
ON r._nos = t._no
,
(SELECT @i := '') temp
ORDER BY _no
```

Output :

```
1   1   vikas           One
    1   kratika         One
1   1   kratika kastwar One
2   2   vikas           two
```

But I am expecting output in **MySQL**  like this

```
1      1    kratika         One
       1    kratika kastwar One
       1    vikas           One
2      2    vikas           two
```

I don't want to use query like this in **MySQL** as desc here [MYSQL Order By W/Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589481/mysql-order-by-w-count)

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN _no = @i THEN '' ELSE @i := _no END
    as row_no,
    _no,
    _name,
    _names
FROM
(SELECT 
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT '1' as _no, 'vikas' as _name UNION ALL
    SELECT '1', 'kratika' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2', 'vikas' UNION ALL
    SELECT '1', 'kratika kastwar' 
) t
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT '1' as _nos, 'One' as _names UNION ALL
    SELECT '2', 'two' 
) r
ON r._nos = t._no
,
(SELECT @i := '') temp
ORDER BY _no) t
```

How I can achieve the same in MySQL, query performance is major parameter

Comment: Why not do the formatting in the front end?

Comment: I want formatting in query itself

Comment: @lc. is right. Things like this belongs on front end. You are giving server extra hard work.

Comment: I think both your queries (for SQL-Server and MySQL) are broken. You need `ORDER BY _no, _name`. In SQL-Server you have only `ORDER BY _no` and in MySQL you have no `ORDER BY` in the external query.

Answer (score 1):

I think what's happening here is that MySQL is constructing the resultset and then going through an extra step to order it according to the ORDER BY clause. Since the `'kratika kastwar'` row comes after the row where `_no` is `2`, you get the unexpected output.

The solution, I guess, would be to put the basic `SELECT` (without the special user-variable shenanigans) in a subquery in the `FROM` clause, applying the `ORDER BY` clause to the subquery. Then do the user-variable work in the outer query. That way the ordering has already happened.

Edit: I see that you said you don't want to do this. I don't think you have a choice, unless you can find a way to get MySQL to not do the `ORDER BY` by performing a filesort step on the computed results (very unlikely).

Comment: you mean there is no solution

Comment: Yes, I think that there is no way to do what you are asking, aside from the solution that you've already said you don't want to use for some reason.

Comment: I don't know much about SQL Server. As I said, I think MySQL is putting together the results without regards to the order and then ordering them after the fact, which is why you get the unwanted `1` in that one line. It's because in the unordered result set that line appears after a line with a different value in that column.

Comment: sorry would you please describe the same

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23630/discussion-between-vikas-and-hammerite)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN _no = @i THEN '' ELSE @i := _no END
    as row_no,
    _no,
    _name,
    _names
FROM
(SELECT 
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT '1' as _no, 'vikas' as _name UNION ALL
    SELECT '1', 'kratika' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2', 'vikas' UNION ALL
    SELECT '1', 'kratika kastwar' 
) t
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT '1' as _nos, 'One' as _names UNION ALL
    SELECT '2', 'two' 
) r
ON r._nos = t._no
,
(SELECT @i := '')
```

Comment: I don't want to use this query as I mentioned in qus